# Как собрать vue компонент для ssr?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Я хочу запускать на сервере компонент manager(это мой самописный компонент). При попытке сделать бил компонента, а затем запустить его на сервере вылетает эта ошибка "document is not defined". В данном контексте

```
var styleElement = document.querySelector('style[' + ssrIdKey + '~="' + obj.id + '"]')
```

Я понимаю, что на сервере нет объекта document, но компонент хочется запустить именно там. Как указать webpack, что нужно делать билд для сервера?

Я уже пробоавл в файле webpack.config.js написать

```
module.exports = {
  target: "node"
};
```

Но из этого ничего не вышло

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, что конфиг вебпака нужно указывать в vue.config.js в поле configureWebpack

Вот как выглядит моё решение

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    target: "node"
  }
};
```

Не ленитесь читать доки. Вот я поленился прочесть доки vue.cli и потратил на эту больше времени, чем мог